# Getting error while running EIM job

Tags: siebel

EIM job is getting error out while running it. Below is my IFB file -

```
"[Siebel Interface Manager]

  USER NAME = 'SADMIN'
  PASSWORD  = 'SADMIN'
  PROCESS   = "PROCESS UPDATE"


[PROCESS UPDATE]

   TYPE = IMPORT
   BATCH = 30032012 - 30032015
   TABLE = EIM_FN_ASSET5
   INSERT ROWS = S_ASSET_CON, FALSE
   UPDATE ROWS = S_ASSET_CON, TRUE
   ONLY BASE TABLES = S_ASSET_CON
   ONLY BASE COLUMNS = S_ASSET_CON.ATTRIB_37,S_ASSET_CON.ATTRIB_38,S_ASSET_CON.ATTRIB_50,S_ASSET_CON.ASSET_ID,S_ASSET_CON.CONTACT_ID,\
    S_ASSET_CON.RELATION_TYPE_CD"
```

In application, it shows error --
 **"SBL-EIM-00426: All batches in run failed."**

I have placed IFB in admin folder itself and below is the log file -

"2021 2012-04-03 05:35:25 2012-04-03 05:35:25 -0500 00000002 001 003f 0001 09 srvrmgr 16187618 1 /004fs02/siebel/siebsrvr/log/srvrmgr.log 8.1.1.4 [21225] ENU
SisnapiLayerLog Error   1   0000000c4f7a00e2:0  2012-04-03 05:35:25    258: [SISNAPI] Async Thread: connection (0x204ec5b0), error (1180682) while reading message"

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Async Thread: connection (0x204ec5b0), error (1180682) while reading message
```

This happens when an object manager lost the connection to the gateway. There can be many reasons for this: Restart the gateway without bouncing the app server. Network issues... etc.

But, this is the error in your **Server Manager** session, not in the **EIM** session (Batch Component). For each EIM job that you start (via server manager) you should see a corresponding EIM tasks.  The best is to see the error in the EIMxxxx.log file. Also, you can debug your EIM task by setting Event Logs levels:

```
change evtloglvl %=3 for comp EIM
(set detailed logging)

(run your EIM job) start task ......

list active tasks for comp EIM
(you should see the job running..)

list tasks for comp EIM
(Or you can see the list of jobs)

change evtloglvl %=1 for comp EIM
(use this line to set the log levels back to "normal")
```

This will give you some detailed info on what the EIM component is doing.  Note: Make use of a small batch or your log will be too big to manage.

If you have some connection errors and you recently lost your DB connection, the best is to completely restart the siebel servers and gateway in the correct order.

Comment: I tried the above, thank you for that.  But I still receive this message in the log SBL-SVR-01042: Internal: Communication protocol error while instantiating new task SBL-EIM-00426: All batches in run failed.  How to fiond out the cause of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried re-runing the EIM Job. 
If the scenario continues even after the second run - Please check the batch number you have given in the IFB file with the batch numbers given in the Input Data file for the EIM component - as from the error it seems that the EIM component is not able to fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

`SBL-SVR-01042` is a generic error when this error is encountered while attempting to instantiate a new instance of a given component and is generic. As to why the error has occurred, one needs to review the accompanying error messages which will help provide context and more detailed information

You can ignore `SisnapiLayerLog Error`. This is generic error and does not have any significance.

You should concentrate on `SBL-EIM-00426`. before running task can you check if there is any record in your EIM table. This error comes when you have zero record in interface table.you should increase log level to high and try to trache error. There is also fixed released by Oracle. Refer oracle support for same.

https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?parent=DOCUMENT&sourceId=498041.1&id=10469733

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the IFB file code little bit and it worked for me.
Can you please try the below code and let me know.

```
[Siebel Interface Manager]

USER NAME = 'SADMIN'
PASSWORD  = 'SADMIN'
PROCESS   = "PROCESS UPDATE"

[PROCESS UPDATE]

TYPE = SHELL
INCLUDE = "Update Records"


[Update Records]

TYPE = IMPORT
BATCH = 30032012 - 30032015
TABLE = EIM_FN_ASSET5
INSERT ROWS = S_ASSET_CON, FALSE
UPDATE ROWS = S_ASSET_CON, TRUE
ONLY BASE TABLES = S_ASSET_CON
ONLY BASE COLUMNS = S_ASSET_CON.ATTRIB_37 \
,S_ASSET_CON.ATTRIB_38 \
,S_ASSET_CON.ATTRIB_50 \
,S_ASSET_CON.ASSET_ID \
,S_ASSET_CON.CONTACT_ID \
,S_ASSET_CON.RELATION_TYPE_CD
```

Hope this helps!